# The Nginx-ingress settings are malfunctioning when the host is configured

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, ingress-controller

I used helm to install ingress-nginx version below

```
sources:
- https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx
version: 4.8.0
```

When I use the following configuration, I can connect to my website normally, but when I add the host and SSL, it doesn't work. Please see the second section

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress-lb
  namespace: dev-frontend
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      more_set_headers "server: angusitlab";
      more_set_headers "X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff";
      more_set_headers "X-Frame-Options: DENY";
      more_set_headers "X-Xss-Protection: 1";
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-modsecurity: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-owasp-core-rules: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/modsecurity-snippet: |
      SecRuleEngine On
      SecDebugLog /tmp/modsec_debug.log
      SecRuleRemoveById 949110
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range: "0.0.0.0/0"
    # # {{auth_type}}
    # # {{auth_secret}}
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx-angusitlab
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - www.angusitlab.com
      secretName: http-secret-dev
  rules:
  - http: 
      paths:
        - path: /
          pathType: ImplementationSpecific
          backend:
            service:
              name: dev-nginx
              port:
                number: 80
```

When I add the host and use certificates, I can't establish a connection no matter what I try.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: dev-nginx-ingress-lb
  namespace: dev-frontend
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      more_set_headers "server: angusitlab";
      more_set_headers "X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff";
      more_set_headers "X-Frame-Options: DENY";
      more_set_headers "X-Xss-Protection: 1";
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-modsecurity: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-owasp-core-rules: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/modsecurity-snippet: |
      SecRuleEngine On
      SecDebugLog /tmp/modsec_debug.log
      SecRuleRemoveById 949110
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range: "0.0.0.0/0"
    # # {{auth_type}}
    # # {{auth_secret}}
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx-angusitlab
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - www.angusitlab.com
      secretName: http-secret-dev
  rules:
    - host: www.angusitlab.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              service:
                name: dev-nginx
                port:
                  number: 80
          - path: /zh-hk/blog.*
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              service:
                name: blog-wordpress
                port:
                  number: 8081
          - path: /en-us/blog.*
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              service:
                name: blog-wordpress
                port:
                  number: 8081
          - path: /zh-hk/wp-.*
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              service:
                name: blog-wordpress
                port:
                  number: 8081
          - path: /en-us/wp-.*
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              service:
                name: blog-wordpress
                port:
                  number: 8081
          - path: /wp-.*
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              service:
                name: blog-wordpress
                port:
                  number: 8081
```

keep getting this result....

```
curl -k -v https://www.angusitlab.com
*   Trying 20.239.2.101:443...
```

I tried rebuilding the AKS cluster, but even with the 4.8.3 version, it's still not working. I'm quite confused... please help!

I found if I apply an ingress with no host and deployment in default namespace, host [www.angusitlab.com](http://www.angusitlab.com) it will work normally... it might be an nginx config ....issue but I can not figure out why it is.

Ingress:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: hello-world-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx-471
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /hello-world-one(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: aks-helloworld-one
            port:
              number: 80
      - path: /hello-world-two(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: aks-helloworld-two
            port:
              number: 80
      - path: /(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: aks-helloworld-one
            port:
              number: 80
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: hello-world-ingress-static
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /static/$2
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /static(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: aks-helloworld-one
            port: 
              number: 80
```

Services and Deployment

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: aks-helloworld-one  
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: aks-helloworld-one
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: aks-helloworld-one
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: aks-helloworld-one
        image: mcr.microsoft.com/azuredocs/aks-helloworld:v1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        env:
        - name: TITLE
          value: "Welcome to Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: aks-helloworld-one  
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - port: 80
  selector:
    app: aks-helloworld-one
```

Comment: SO is for programming questions

Comment: this is ingress-nginx which was applied to azure kubernetes saas AKS cluster, but not working ~